# How to set a path in ubuntu such that i can run my eclipse-juno in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I want to set PATH var in ubuntu such that i can run my programs by just giving their name in terminal.

I created a folder **/home/vignesh/bin** and keep my eclipse folder there

and in **~/.bashrc** is gave this command:

> export PATH=${PATH}:/home/vignesh/bin/eclipse/eclipse

(I logging out and logging in again)
but when i type eclipse i get this message in terminal as:

The program 'eclipse' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install eclipse-platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the /etc/environment by adding the path to the eclipse executable, as follow:

1- take a backup of /etc/environment

2- $sudo nano /etc/environment
e.g.:
PATH="/path1:/path2:/home/sasa/eclipse"

3-Then restart your computer